# Can't publish Usb camera image with ROS CvBridge and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, camera, usb, ros

I'm trying to publish an opencv image using usb_camera, ros_bridge. Topic is published  but I can't see any image or error. I can see usb_camera image

```
class image_converter:
  def __init__(self):
    self.image_pub = rospy.Publisher("/image_converter/image_topic_2",Image, queue_size=10)
    self.bridge = CvBridge()
    self.image_sub =     rospy.Subscriber("/webcam/image_raw",Image,self.callback)

  def callback(self,data):
    try:
      cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")
    except CvBridgeError as e:
      print(e)
    grey = cv2.cv_image(cv_image,(7,7))
    edges =cv2.canny(grey,15.0,30.0)

    try:
    self.image_pub.publish(self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(edges, "bgr8"))
    except CvBridgeError as e:
      print(e)

def main(args):
  image_converter()
  rospy.init_node('image_converter', anonymous=True)
  try:
    rospy.spin()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Shutting down")
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In your `main` function you should call `rospy.init_node` first, before doing any ROS-related stuff like creating publishers/subscribers.

Comment: I changed  the main function:
  
`rospy.init_node('image_converter', anonymous=True)
  image_converter()`
I stll can't see opencv image

Comment: @user1849595 Sorry for the late response. Just to be sure: have you double-checked that there are images published on the subscribed topic `/webcam/image_raw`? You can do this for example by calling `rostopic echo /webcam/image_raw`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, I lack mad python skills, but you are only calling the "constructor" of a class without assigning it to anything, doesn't that mean it will have a refcount of 0 and automatically be garbage collected?